# How to automatically re-run failed TestNG tests on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I'm working on the last stages of building a Selenium automation suite for an enterprise environment. It's configured with TestNG, running on Jenkins. The suite consists mostly of UI tests. As typical of this setup the tests are flaky, and re-working the tests to be less dependent on UI automation is not feasible within our timeline.

Given that I'm already working on code optimization, I'd like to set something up that automatically re-runs failed tests to minimise the need for manual investigation of failures. I've investigated a couple of options, but none quite work for our setup:

- An ideal solution would be to use the [Maven Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html) plugin which has a `rerunFailingTestsCount` property, but this feature is only supported for JUnit (we use TestNG)
- The Jenkins [Flaky Test Handler](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flaky+Test+Handler+Plugin) plugin was developed by the same folks^ and appears to depend on JUnit as well

Suggestions for a solution that would work with our setup would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest, that you just work with a RetryAnalyzer, which would force a failed test to be retried again. The solution of relying on the `testng-failed.xml` that is being talked about in the link shared by @sumit (the alternatives were proposed by me only in that thread) is a bit cumbersome when you are dealing with getting your test reports to be merged properly.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan thanks for that, a cursory search produced this blog post that appears promising: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-correctly-implement-retryanalyzer-testng-sagar-shroff/
Does that look like a good implementation to you?

Comment: Sure, it looks decent enough and worth a good start.

Comment: Hi @KrishnanMahadevan, I got some time to try the RetryAnalyzer and have it working when included directly in the test invocation. However, I am running into an issue with setting up the lTransformAnnotation listener in order to apply the annotation to all test methods. The testng.xml seems to not be processed at all. I have the Maven Surefire plugin installed and configured in pom.xml. What else could I be missing?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I was wondering if there is a simple way to re-run testng like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055475/make-jenkins-run-failed-test-automatically instead of implementing a lot of code. If its not there, then I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Retry Listener:

Retry Class:

```
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;

import org.testng.ITestResult;


public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;

    private int maxRetryCount = 1;


    public String getResultStatusName(int status) {

        String resultName = null;

        if (status == 1)

            resultName = "SUCCESS";

        if (status == 2)

            resultName = "FAILURE";

        if (status == 3)

            resultName = "SKIP";

        return resultName;

    }


    /*

     * Below method returns 'true' if the test method has to be retried else

     * 'false' and it takes the 'Result' as parameter of the test method that

     * just ran

     * 

     * @see org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer#retry(org.testng.ITestResult)

     */

    @Override

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {

            System.out.println("Retrying test " + result.getName() + " with status " + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) + " for the " + (retryCount + 1) + " time(s).");

            retryCount++;

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }
```

And add this listener:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;


import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;

import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;


public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {


    @Override

    public void transform(ITestAnnotation testannotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

        IRetryAnalyzer retry = testannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();


        if (retry == null) {

            testannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);

        }

    }


}
```

You have 2 options to call above listener:

From your xml testng runner as bellow:

```
<listeners>

        <listener class-name="package path....com.listeners.RetryListener" />

        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />

        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />

</listeners>
```

From the test class:

```
@Listeners({ package path....com.listeners.RetryListener })
```

You need to add above declaration before the class declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried using the `@Listeners` annotation. However using this method, the overridden `transform()` method in the `IAnnotationTransformer` class is never called (verified using a coverage tool). From the TestNG documentation, it appears that `IAnnotationTransformer` is not supposed to be supported for the `@Listener` annotation. Has this method worked for you previously?

Comment: Excerpt from [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):

"The @Listeners annotation can contain any class that extends org.testng.ITestNGListener except IAnnotationTransformer and IAnnotationTransformer2. The reason is that these listeners need to be known very early in the process so that TestNG can use them to rewrite your annotations, therefore you need to specify these listeners in your testng.xml file."

Comment: Tina,
Yes it's working for me.
According to Oracle java doc: 
Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the compiler to detect errors or suppress warnings.Compile-time and deployment-time processing — Software tools can process annotation information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.
And yes java will suggest to add unused function annotation for transform method but yes it will be called in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For the failed testNG tests, the failure report is stored as testngfialed.xml. Add that to your XML Suite, something like this should work:

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
  <suiteXmlFile>src/test/<your path>.../testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
  <suiteXmlFile>target/surefire-reports/testngfailed.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

This might hep: [Run testngfailed.xml via Jenkins](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/Ei_F2R6qRjE)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This response replaces a previous response that got deleted by a moderator. See the next response for details of how to define and connect a TestNG retry analyzer. I'd prefer for my response to follow that one, but it shows up here instead.

In addition to the TestNG suite file method shown below, you can specify the retry analyzer is via a service loader configuration file. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader

This ServiceLoader mechanism has the advantage of working as expected regardless of the how the project is defined or how it gets run.